# what is definition of device memory in ARMv8?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, device, device-driver

In ARMv8 TRM:
An unaligned access to any type of Device memory causes an Alignment fault.

What is meant by device memory. 
Can we call PCIe BAR memory on End point cards as device memory ?

So when EP bars are mapped to host memory, can we call this set of memory as device memory ?

Comment: Exactly which manual are you referring to?  The ARM Architecture Reference_Manual for ARMv8 & v8-A has lengthy descriptions of Normal and Device memory.

Comment: ARMv8, generally pcie bars are memeory mapped. By this we can consider them as device memory.
Who sets this memory type attribute in linux and on what basis ?

Answer (score 0):

Whether a certain memory region is defined as device memory depends on several things. First you need have at least one of the fields in MAIR_ELx register defined as device memory (see ARM ARM for exact configuration) . Secondly, in your translation tables, region mapped as device memory should point to that specific MAIR_ELx index in its lower attributes ( AttrIdx[4:2] bits).